# How to interpolate an Elixir list in an execute statement in Ecto migrations?

Tags: elixir, ecto

How do I perform this migration:

```
types = ["a", "b", "c"]
execute "UPDATE table SET type='d' WHERE type in #{types}"
```

Normally, you would do something like this:

```
execute "UPDATE table SET type='d' WHERE type in ('a', 'b', 'c')"
```

but what if the types come from a list of a variable length?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a (probably bad) way of doing it:

```
types = ["a", "b", "c"]
execute "UPDATE table SET type='d' WHERE type in ('#{Enum.join(types, "', '")}')"
```

That just builds the string. There is probably a better way, involving passing a function to `execute`, like this (from the docs):

```
execute(fn -> repo().query!("select 'Anonymous function query …';", [], [log: :info]) end)
```

https://hexdocs.pm/ecto_sql/Ecto.Migration.html#execute/1

which would look like:

```
execute(fn -> repo().query!("update table set type='d' where type = any($1)", [types]) end)
```

Comment: Thanks to @potibas for providing correct `execute` syntax.